# Running python file as intent handling command in rhasspy

Tags: python-3.x, docker, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a python file as an intent handler in rhasspy. I placed the following content in the intent handling section of the settings page:

```
python3 /home/user/path/file.py
```

Python can't find it even when I give the full path to any location. It returns:

```
[DEBUG:2022-12-03 18:44:45,278] rhasspyremote_http_hermes: python3: can't open file '/home/user/path/file.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So, where do I place this file for rhasspy to find it?
(I am running rhasspy using docker)

Answer (score 1):

If you started it via docker i suggest you use the "docker-storage"-path.
I.e. if you started Rhasspy via

```
docker run -d -p 12101:12101 \
  --name rhasspy \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  -v "$HOME/.config/rhasspy/profiles:/profiles" \
  -v "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro" \
  --device /dev/snd:/dev/snd \
  rhasspy/rhasspy \
  --user-profiles /profiles \
  --profile en
```

you should take a look at `"$HOME/.config/rhasspy/profiles:/profiles" \`